# vue3 disable next page & prev page in the browser when inside the same route path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, router

Today I'm facing a problem and I could use some advice.

I have a route page structure like {url}/:id. My objective is to prevent users from navigating to the previous and next pages within the same route, for example, from {url}/1 to {url}/2. I am making API calls to change the data on the page, and the URL does change accordingly.

However, I want users to be able to navigate to the page before or after the {url}/:id, but not within the {url}/:id itself.

Is there any solution or advice you can provide? I have heard that navigation guards might be helpful, but I find them difficult to understand initially.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

---

Sorry for bad explanation, I need the browser remember the prev page or next page is another, like {url}/lists or {url}/news, but does not remember the same route page, so it won't go to the same route page after clicking the button on the browser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a high-level example using Vue Router:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.params.id && from.params.id) {
    if (to.params.id !== from.params.id) {
      next(); // Allow navigation to the next page within the route
    } else {
      next(false); // Block navigation to the same page within the route
    }
  } else {
    next(); // Allow navigation to other routes
  }
});
```

Comment: is there any possibility that the browser won't show the prev & next button clickable when it's in the same route ? thx

Comment: sorry may be mistaken, I need the browser remember the prev page or next page is another, like {url}/lists or {url}/news, but does not remember the same route page, so it won't go to the same route page

Answer (score 0):

I found that

```
this.$router.replace({ path: '/your-route' });
```

instead of

```
router.push
```

solved my problem.